# How do I configure the available memory in my PHP-FPM pools?

Tags: php, fastcgi

I have 20 GB available for PHP-FPM on my server, the average consumption of my PHP-FPM pools is 55 MB. I want to create a www.conf for the site and a www2.conf for routines that run during the day.

I was wondering if I should configure the two files, considering 20 GB of memory, in which case my pm.max_children would be 20000/55 = 363, or if I should divide the memory between the two, for example, leaving 12 GB for the site what would give me an pm.max_children of 12000/55 = 218, and 8 GB for routines, what would give me an pm.max_children of 8000/55 = 145?

How should I configure these 20 GB of available memory in my two ".conf" files?